# The development server returned error code: 500

Tags: react-native

[image: Image to the error]

I'm trying to run an android project on the android studio emulator and every time I'm getting this error message can anyone help please? I linked an image above

**package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProjec",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1",
    "jest": "23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of RN and which OS?

Comment: Do you have babel-core in your dev dependencies ? (could you share your package.json please)

Comment: @AravindS im using RN version 0.55 and OS windows 10

Comment: @zarnifoulette No i don't have babel core. what should i do then ?

Comment: @zarnifoulette sorry i'm new to React-native so can you tell me how to share package.json

Comment: @zarnifoulette also everytime i try to run this commands in my project the cmd shuts down alone without touching it  npm uninstall --save babel-preset-react-native
npm install --save babel-preset-react-native@4.0.0

Comment: RN .56 in window 10 have some issues..RN is still fixing it...so better downgrade your version

Comment: @AravindS but i was using RN .55.4  and my CLI is v1.2.0 should i downgrade again ??

Comment: Please share your package.json

Comment: @AravindS i just shared it in my question above

Comment: Can you try this `npm install babel-core babel-loader --save-dev`

Comment: @AravindS inside the project directory right?

Comment: @AravindS This is what i get after running this command : npm WARN babel-loader@7.1.5 requires a peer of webpack@2 || 3 || 4 but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native@0.55.4 requires a peer of react@16.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN The package babel-core is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package babel-loader is included as both a dev and production dependency.

Comment: @AravindS and still the same error exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create the project with below command:-

```
react-native init ProjectName --version react-native@0.55.0
```

Comment: Thank you very very much that saved me a lot of time really i appreciate your help.